# Tableau Server: How to Disable Trusted Authentication

Tags: tableau-api

I am able to add remove IP addresses to tableau server, but I can not find any documentation explaining on how to disable Tableau Trusted IP addresses. Any idea of how to open tableau server to world?!?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you are looking for `wgserver.extended_trusted_ip_checking=false` but the default is `false` where Tableau does not enforce client IP address matching.

From the command line:

```
tsm configuration set -k wgserver.extended_trusted_ip_checking -v false
```

This also depends on your server version as tsm is available only after 2018.2

Comment: Thanks `tabadmin set wgserver.extended_trusted_ip_checking false` does the same in older version. Interestingly the value is already set to false! But IP checking is enabled :/